# Find complement of image in matlab without using function imcomplement?

Tags: image, matlab

I have been working on Matlab and can't find the code for complement of the image without using function

```
 binstring = dec2bin(Image1, 8);
 binImage = ~binstring;
 binImage = 1-binImage;
 binImage = (binImage == 0);
 figure,imshow(binImage);
```

Comment: I don't get the question. Please provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

From MATLAB's `imcomplement` documentation:

> If IM is a grayscale or RGB image of class double, you can use the expression 1-IM instead of this function. If IM is a binary image, you can use the expression ~IM instead of this function.

This following code snippet should explain the above tip clearly.

```
img=imread('cameraman.tif');
img1=imcomplement(im2double(img));
img2=1-im2double(img);
isequal(img1,img2)
```